# PHP7.3(2) FPM + Oracle OCI8 Extension not loading

Tags: php, ubuntu, oracle-call-interface, forge

I am using Laravel Forge, running lemp servers. I've tried 7.2 and 7.3, on Ubuntu 18.04.
I went through this tutorial to try an install oci8 extension. It seems to have installed in cli, as I can tell by `php -m` but no loading, and no errors via fpm.
I went through this tutorial - https://gist.github.com/hewerthomn/81eea2935051eb2500941a9309bca703
I installed 12_2 (64 bit) instantclient basic and SDK, via pecl.

I see the oci8.so file located here - /usr/lib/php/20180731
I have the loading extension stanza at the end of my cli and fpm ini files.
I have tried php 7.2 and 7.3.
Obviously we're getting this error in Laravel simply because the extension isn't loading - https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/issues/506

Help please!

Comment: Did you run ldconfig, as per the instructions?

Comment: Yeah - my coworker was able to get things running upgrading the software. Apparently 12 didn't play well with php 7.3